# Having troubles w/ drawing hourglass with asterisks in Java. (nested loops) (user decides # of rows)

Tags: java, nested-loops

as the title states, I'm having problems drawing this hourglass figure. The goal is to have the user choose the number of rows (has to be odd and positive) and then draw the hourglass with that info. The top and bottom row will have the same amount of asterisks as there are rows.

Should look something like this:

```
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double nRows;
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter an odd-number of output-lines (enter zero to exit the program): ");
    nRows = console.nextDouble();


    for(int row=1; row<=nRows; row++ )
        {
            for(int column = 1; column<=nRows-row; column++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for(int column = 1; column<= row*2-1; column++)
                System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

This prints the bottom triangle.
The problem I'm having troubles with is finding out the equation to print the top half. I assume that once I figure out the code for the top half, I'll have to use if statements to tell it when to switch between the top half and the bottom half?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: updated the variables to be a little easier to read.

As for what I've been told thus far, here is my understanding:

```
for( int row = nRows; row>=1; row--)
   {
     for ( int column = 1; column<=nRows-ir; column++)
             System.out.print(" ");
     for ( int column = 1; column<=row*2-1; column++)
             System.out.print("*");
     System.out.println();
   }
```

Comment: `nRows` should be an `int` not a `double`, Copy the `for` loops you have and decrement the indices instead of increment. You will also need to adjust the bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the decrementing part. What do you mean by update the bounds. As in ir should start at nRows and go down instead of going from 1 up? Will that be the same for all indices? @PEF

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming "ir" is for the column and "ic" is for the row (a bit confusing). There's no equation to make it do the top, all you'd have to do is take the same code you use the generate the bottom and have it iterate in the opposite order. This can be done by making ic start as the maximum and having it decrement instead of increment. I'd include a code snippet of my own, but I'd having a little bit of trouble reading that. (Please name your variables after what they represent. For example, row and column instead of ic and ir)

Hope I helped!

Comment: Yes, that would iterate in the reverse order.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to type that there! I updated the code to be more readable like you said and also added what my understanding of what you told me. @Redempt

Comment: Ah, what you said now makes sense to me. I tried it in my code and it worked as you said it would and that concept is now clear in my head. Unfortunately, the concept you offered was simply to mirror what I had already done. This resulted in there being two rows of single asterisks when there should only have been one.

Comment: What I meant is that you should copy the original loop, then put the copied loop above the original one and make that one loop in reverse order. Copy the entire loop, including the one iterating with "row".

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  int nRows;
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Please enter an odd-number of output-lines (enter zero to exit the program): ");
  nRows = console.nextInt();

for(int i=0; i < nRows/2; i++ ) {
    for(int j = nRows - i; j < nRows; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < nRows - 2*i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

for(int i=0; i < (nRows+1)/2; i++ )
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= nRows/2 - i; j++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    for(int j = 0; j <= i*2; j++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: This indeed does work. Did starting from 0 instead of 1 give you any advantage there? I see that you chose to start from nRows - i at one point.  What goes into deciding where to begin from? @PEF

Comment: I started from `i=0` since the first line req's zero spaces before the `*`'s begin. Next, I looked at the sequence of pairs of integers needed for the case where `nRows=7`. i.e: (0,7), (1,5), (2,5), (3,1), (2,5), (1,5), (0,7) where the number on the left is the number of spaces to print and on the right, the number of `*`'s to print. Then I decided to let the first 2 `for` loops print the 1st 3 of these pairs (upside-down triangle missing the bottom `*`) and the last 2 `for` loops print the right-side-up triangle. Deciding where to begin is a matter of preference and experience.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this out.

The outer for loop will determine the height of the hourglass.
The inner for loop will prints the `*` to show the pattern.

Hope this help the other who might need this somehow.

```
public static void hourGlass(int size) {
    // 2 for loops only
    int dimension = (size * 2) - 1, space = 0, stars = size - 1, printed = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<dimension; i++) {
        int actual = space;
        for (int j=dimension; j > 0; j--) {
            if(actual > 0) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                actual--;
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("*");
                if(stars==printed) {
                    actual = space;
                    printed = 0;
                } else {
                    actual = 1;
                    printed++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(i <= size-2) { // will pattern spaces and stars from top to middle
            space++;
            stars--;
        }
        else { // will pattern spaces and stars from middle to top
            space--;
            stars++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes